# What you gotta do?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, word-property, connect-wall

You have 10 groups of 4 words:

> 1. DUO, IRON, LINKS, ROCK
> 2. ICE, LED, METAL, TIC
> 3. DRILL, PI, WIN, WOO
> 4. BRA, IGNITE, LOOM, RUBBISH
> 5. AIR, DUST, GO, PAT
> 6. AUDI, AURA, MEOW, SPEW
> 7. GRIMM, HOOT, MUD, TAIL
> 8. ASK, BELL, CATER, MEDIC
> 9. BLITZ, CRUST, PLUS, SQUIRT
> 10. CHERUB, SEE, SHIN, STEEL

And another group of 10 words:

> A, LAUNCHER, NON, NOONE, NUN, PURR, TUN, TWO, WEED, WORM

The question is: **What you gotta do?** (The answer is 10 letters long)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Extending @QuantumTwinkie's answer, and using the connect-wall tag, notice that there is a connection between each group of four words. (Note: I never would have gotten this without QuantumTwinkie's answer, so this is a true tag team effort.)

DUO, IRON, LINKS, ROCK

> Makes Pokemon when a note (do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, ti) is added
>
>  **DO**DUO, **LA**IRON, **FA**LINKS, **SOL**ROCK

ICE, LED, METAL, TIC

> Makes Pokemon when a traditionally male name is added
>
>  **REG**ICE, LED**IAN**, **MEL**METAL, **MILO**TIC

DRILL, PI, WIN, WOO

> Makes Pokemon when flying animal is added
>
>  **BEE**DRILL, PI**DOVE**, WIN**GULL**, WOO**BAT**

BRA, IGNITE, LOOM, RUBBISH

> Makes Pokemon when a single letter is added at the beginning of the word
>
>  **A**BRA, **P**IGNITE, **G**LOOM, **T**RUBBISH

AIR, DUST, GO, PAT

> Makes Pokemon when an animal in the Chinese zodiac is added
>
>  **DRAGON**AIR, DUST**OX**, GO**GOAT**, PAT**RAT**

AUDI, AURA, MEOW, SPEW

> Makes Pokemon when a two letter atomic symbol is added
>  Specifically, the atomic symbol of an actinide series element...thanks to @oAlt.
>
>  AUDI**NO**, **AM**AURA, MEOW**TH**, SPEW**PA**

GRIMM, HOOT, MUD, TAIL

> Makes Pokemon when word describing a sound is added
>
>  GRIMM**SNARL**, HOOT**HOOT**, MUD**BRAY**, TAIL**LOW** (low as in cows lowing)

ASK, BELL, CATER, MEDIC

> Makes Pokemon when a food is added
>
>  **YAM**ASK, BELL**SPROUT**, CATER**PIE**, MEDIC**HAM**

BLITZ, CRUST, PLUS, SQUIRT

> Makes Pokemon when "le" is added to the end
>
>  BLITZ**LE**, CRUST**LE**, PLUS**LE**, SQUIRT**LE**

CHERUB, SEE, SHIN, STEEL

> Makes Pokemon when Roman number is added
>
>  CHERUB**I**, SEE**L**, SHIN**X**, STEEL**IX**

A, LAUNCHER, NON, NOONE, NUN, PURR, TUN, TWO, WEED, WORM

> This group of 10 contains one member from each of the previous groups!
>
>  **HORSE**A, **C**LAUNCHER, **TOUCAN**NON, **LI**NOONE, **MI**NUN, **ES**PURR, **APPLE**TUN, **MEW**TWO, WEED**LE**, WORM**ADAM**

Finishing up:

> First, reorder the Pokemon in the tenth group to correspond with the order of the categories as they appear above:
>
>  **MI**NUN, WORM**ADAM**, **TOUCAN**NON, **C**LAUNCHER, **HORSE**A, **ES**PURR, **MEW**TWO, **APPLE**TUN, WEED**LE**, **LI**NOONE
>
>  Then take the first letter of each added component to read **MATCH 'EM ALL!**.

Comment: YES! This is a perfect answer - well done :) You can, in fact, be even more specific about the connection for group 6...

Comment: @Stiv I don't know if it matters, but all those are either lanthanides or actinides, are they not? :0

Comment: @oAlt Pick one! (Yes) :)

Comment: Thanks @oAlt! It actually does matter...if I had seen that, it would have made the last step easier, since I originally messed it up.

Comment: Great finds!! :)

Comment: @Stiv heh, I'm dumb. At first I thought "Th" was thulium instead of thorium.

Comment: @oAlt Well, there is Iodeen and Thorium and Thulium and Thallium. You did better than me...at first I was confused because all the rest were two-letter words, but this darn "TH" was not. I completely forgot about No.

Answer (score 11):

> Many of these words relate to Pokemon.

DUO, IRON, LINKS, ROCK

> **Dou**blade(Houn**dou**r), *La**iron***, *Fa**links***, Sol**rock**(Regi**rock**)

ICE, LED, METAL, TIC

> Reg**ice**, **Led**yba(**Led**ian), *Mel**metal***, Milo**tic**

DRILL, PI, WIN, WOO

> Bee**drill**(Exca**drill**), **Pi**plup, S**win**ub, **Woo**bat

BRA, IGNITE, LOOM, RUBBISH

> A**bra**, P**ignite**, G**loom**, T**rubbish**

AIR, DUST, GO, PAT

> Celf**air**y(Dragon**air**), **Dust**ox, **Gogo**at(Pan**go**ro), **Pat**rat

AUDI, AURA, MEOW, SPEW

> **Audi**no, Am**aura**, **Meow**th, **Spew**pa

GRIMM, HOOT, MUD, TAIL

> **Grimm**snarl, **Hoothoot**, **Mud**kip, **Tail**low

ASK, BELL, CATER, MEDIC

> Ninj**ask**, **Bell**sprout, **Cater**pie, **Medic**ham

BLITZ, CRUST, PLUS, SQUIRT

> **Blitz**le, **Crust**le, **Plus**le, **Squirt**le

CHERUB, SEE, SHIN, STEEL

> **Cherub**i, **See**dot, **Shin**x, Regi**steel**(**Steel**ix)

A, LAUNCHER, NON, NOONE, NUN, PURR, TUN, TWO, WEED, WORM

> St**a**k**a**t**a**k**a**, C**launcher**, Tuacan**non**, Li**noone**, Mi**nun**, Es**purr**, S**tun**ky, Mew**two**, **Weed**le, **Worm**adam

That means,

> You gotta **catch 'em all**!

Comment: You have the seed of an idea here, but there's still a lot to solve...! Note the tags... :)

Comment: @Stiv, I will keep looking!

Comment: Note: These are not just random lists - why have I carefully chosen them? (Again, see the tags) Also, your guess at the final answer is educated but not yet correct. Among your guesses, you have correctly identified 42 of the 50 so far - you need to choose between some of your ambiguities and replace others which are incorrect. So how can you decide which ones are right and which are wrong?? Hmmm...

Comment: Sorry to snipe! I was just going to comment about the categories, but then I realized I had the whole thing. I never would have gotten it without your answer, though!